# What does the ° symbol mean , as in F#°?

Tags: guitar, sheet-music

The internet search engine seems not to recognize it, so I cannot search for it there! I had assumed it was "augmented" but am now very unsure.
Thanks

Comment: Diminishing returns from a search engine, eh?

Comment: @thrig - searching for nothing (o) was never going to be easy...

Comment: I cannot think that this has not been asked before.

Comment: @thrig Availability or lack thereof of any information via a web search is not to be a criterion on Stack Exchange. We want to be a (top?) hit on search engines, which means we want to have the answers here even if those answers are available elsewhere.

Comment: _"The internet search engine"_?

Comment: I found it searching for "music theory chord symbol °" on Google. It even shows up in a helpful table!

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I think thrig was being punny.

Comment: @ToddWilcox   he was most definitely making a pun that was too sharp for you.   We're all in ac-chord.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - hope your comment doesn't fall flat - could be a natural reaction, barring any other response. Just a breve comment, don't want to cause any treble...

Comment: The symbol ° means diminished.  F#° would be an "F sharp diminished" chord.  The augmented symbol would be +.

Answer (score 11):

Augmented is '+'. The 'o' is diminished. With your example of F#o the notes involved are F#, A, C. The diminished seventh chord will include Eb, although I can't remember ever seeing the symbol 'o7'.

Comment: Or at least F#, A, and C.  I think most people would omit the Eb unless the chord name had a 7 attached?

Comment: @L3B - thanks, edited. Funny, but I often include that bit when a dim chord is on a chart!

Comment: F#° pretty much implies Eb, as this note does not add any color, and I don't recall having ever seen the symbol °7 (but I have seen +7). Also note that this is a *diminished* seventh, not a minor one. Finally, you surely cannot play E natural with this chord though, or the symbol would have been that of a half-diminished chord, another harmony.

Comment: @AlexandreC. - exactly. the half dim chord is subtly different, often called m7b5.

Comment: Not subtly, but completely different. F#° is eg. a V in G (and also in other tones), and F#m7b5 is a II in E minor.

Comment: @AlexandreC. - subtle was not the apposite word!

Answer (score 4):

More specific to the question of what the degree sign means is that yes it is a diminished chord and that means that the chord has the notes that form a minor third from the root and a diminished fifth from the root.

So, as Tim mentions, in this case, it will be F#, A (minor third) and F# to C (diminished fifth)

Answer (score 1):

Different editors/publishers seem to notate certain chords differently, but a fairly common scheme is to describe an C diminished triad (C-Eb-Gb) as C(b5), an C half-diminished 7th (C-Eb-Gb-Bb) as Cm7(b5), and a C full-diminished 7th (C-Eb-Gb-Bbb) as C°.  Note that a C full-diminished-7th is enharmonically the same as a diminished triad with an added major *6th* (C-Eb-Gb-A), and because it would be weird to describe a note nine frets up as a "seventh" (rather than a major sixth) but it would also be weird suggest that the top two notes of the chord are only separated by a second when they're three frets apart, using the C° notation is a simple way of saying that chord note contains pitches that are spaced upward at intervals of three frets starting at C without having to worry about what those notes should be called.

Comment: I'd spell C7b5 as C E Gb Bb. Wouldn't it be C Eb Gb Bb for half dim, Cm7b5?

Comment: @Tim: Corrected.  The way I tune my guitar, half-diminished chords and full-diminished chords are easy to play and sound great, but the major-7-flat-5 is quite a bit more awkward so I sometimes forget about that chord.  When writing out my own tabs, I use a slashed circle for half-diminished chords since I find all the stuff with parentheses harder to read while playing.

Comment: Sometimes see it written Cm7-5, obviating parentheses. Slashed circle is good - can't find it on my qwerty board, though! Same with 'degree'.

Comment: @Tim: The Javascript thing I wrote for my guitar tabs takes chord names in ASCII and then substitutes suitable characters for sharps, flats, slashed or unslashed circles, etc.  So typing Abho7 will produce a fingering symbol with a big 6 over it showing the index finger across five strings (6th fret) and the middle finger on the next fret,  and something like A♭⊘₇ (I forget which circle-slash character I used) underneath it.